# How to get same properties from different parent modules in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with this structure.

[image]

I want to use same jar in different EARs with different properties.
When I run "mvn install", it creates 2 EARs but it cannot do filtering with this config. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please post the pom and the config that you want to change with maven ?

Comment: So `${conf.path}` is somehow hardcoded in JAR2?

Comment: @lexicore no. It uses parent properties and do filtering in xml files.

Comment: @ErkanErol How can both WAR1 and WAR2 be parent of JAR2? Or what do the arros mean on your diagramm?

Comment: @lexicore both depend on same jar

Comment: @ErkanErol You said. JAR2 uses *parent* properties for filtering. What is the parent of JAR2 then? Which parent properties are used?

Answer (score 0):

With Maven, you cannot filter a file belonging to a JAR module which is already built.
Each module is built and packaged separately. So, if you JAR needs to have a property which the value is populated dynamically, I may propose you two solutions :

- Put the properties file which contains the key-value for `conf.path` in each EARs and in the JAR side, you could use a helper class  to lookup in the classpath the value associated to the `conf.path` key.
  You can perform this processing when the value is required or as soon as the application has started up if you need it very soon.
- Create two flavors of your JAR whose the property differs. In this case, the property information is not stored any longer in the EAR but directly in the JAR
  [Look at the `classifier` element](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) :

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from
>   the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and
>   arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name
>   just after the version number. As a motivation for this element,
>   consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE
>   1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the
>   second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.
>
> Another common use case for classifiers is the need to attach
>   secondary artifacts to the project's main artifact. If you browse the
>   Maven central repository, you will notice that the classifiers sources
>   and javadoc are used to deploy the project source code and API docs
>   along with the packaged class files.

To produce multiple jars, configure the `maven-jar-plugin` plugin in your build in this way :

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>jarVersion2</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/jarVersion2.properties</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>jarVersion1</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/jarVersion1.properties</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

After you can reference in your WAR the jarVersion artifact like that for the war 1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupIdOfTheJar</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactIdOfTheJar</artifactId>
        <version>versionOfTheJar</version>
        <classifier>jarVersion1</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

And like that for the war 2 :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupIdOfTheJar</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactIdOfTheJar</artifactId>
        <version>versionOfTheJar</version>
        <classifier>jarVersion2</classifier>
    </dependency>
```